# how do I pass a variable name to an argument in a function

Tags: r

I am a new user to `R` and I want to recall a block of code for different variables and I want to do something like this:

```
   myfunc<- function(dat, groupvar, interestvar){
      a<- dat%>% group_by(groupvar) %>% summarize(m=mean(interestvar))
         ..... other codes ....
      return(a)   }

myfunc(data=newdata, groupvar=variable1, interestvar=variable3)
myfunc(data=newdata, groupvar=variable2, interestvar=varaible4)
```

Here the `variable1-vari` all are variables inside `newdata`. It seems if I call `intrestvar=newdata$varaible3`, that part will work. However, the way I call `groupvar` still don't tell the function the group by is done by `variable1`. How do I make it work?

Comment: Use `{{}}`in the function i.e `a<- dat%>% group_by({{groupvar}}) %>% summarize(m=mean({{interestvar}}))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use curly-curly operator (`{{}}`) from `rlang` to pass unquoted variable in the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

myfunc<- function(dat, groupvar, interestvar){
  a<- dat%>% group_by({{groupvar}}) %>% summarize(m=mean({{interestvar}}))
  return(a)   
}

myfunc(dat =mtcars, groupvar=cyl, interestvar=mpg)
#   cyl        m
#  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     4 26.66364
#2     6 19.74286
#3     8 15.1    

myfunc(dat = mtcars, groupvar=am, interestvar=disp)
#     am        m
#  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     0 290.3789
#2     1 143.5308
```

Comment: Thanks. the curly bracket works. But I got more questions if I add few more lines: 
          a<- dat%>% group_by(groupvar) %>%     
              summarise(q3=quantile({{interestVar1}}, probs=0.75, type=1),
              q1=quantile({{interestVar1}}, probs=0.25, type=1))%>% 
       mutate(iqr=(q3-q1), lowerbound=q1 -1.5*iqr , upperbound=q3 +1.5*iqr) %>% select(year_month_sort_key, lowerbound, upperbound)  }
  It gave me error and said the groupvar1 is not found in iqr. Also, I couldn't call iqr, (or if I use return(dat2) and I could not call it either.Sorry for asking basic questions.

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to ask that as a new question as this information was not shared in the original question.